# Prove $|a+b+c| \leq |a| + |b| + |c|$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: inequality

Here is the proof that I am currently working on.

> Prove $|a+b+c| \leq |a| + |b| + |c|$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. Hint: Apply the triangle inequality twice. Do *not* consider eight cases.

I am not sure I really understand how to actually *use* the triangle inequality. I have a proof for the general triangle inequality, which I can understand and work through.

I get the feeling that I should start by some bunching up the elements, so I'd look into starting with something like this. By associativity:

> $|a+b+c| = |(a+b)+c| \leq |a+b| + |c| \leq |a| + |b| + |c|$

Then I'm not sure where I would go.

My question for MS is if this would seem an appropriate start, and if I could receive some direction for how to set up my cases for this proof.

Comment: The line "$|a+b+c| = |(a+b)+c| \leq |a+b| + |c| \leq |a| + |b| + |c|$" is exactly what the hint meant by applying the triangle inequality twice.

Comment: I don't see the issue here. You proved the proposition correctly, using the triangle inequality twice. It's an appropriate start as well as an appropriate end!

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Is it really that easy?? Man, I'm making this too hard...

Comment: It really is that easy, if you already have the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\\ a\le \left| a \right| ,-a\le \left| a \right| \quad \\ b\le \left| a \right| ,-b\le \left| b \right| $$

$$a+b\le \left| a \right| +\left| b \right| \quad    (1)$$
$$-\left( a+b \right) \le \left| a \right| +\left| b \right|   \quad(2) $$
combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$\left| a+b \right| \le \left| a \right| +\left| b \right| $$
by induction you can prove it:

$$\left| a_{ 1 }+{ a }_{ 2 }+...+{ a }_{ n } \right| \le \left| a_{ 1 } \right| +\left| a_{ 2 } \right| +...+\left| a_{ n } \right| $$

Answer (score 0):

You arrived at the conclusion, there is nothing more to prove!

You know that

$$|(a+b)+c|\leq |a+b|+|c|$$
$$|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$$

Putting these together gives:

$$|a+b+c|\leq |a|+|b|+|b|$$

This is exactly your proof, there is nothing more to show.

However, if you want a challenge, try proving:

$$|x_1+\dots+x_n|\leq|x_1|+\dots+|x_n|$$

Hint: induction.

Comment: This "challenge" might also have him exclaim, "Is it really that easy??" again when he's done with it.

Comment: @columbus8myhw *...when she's done with it.*

Comment: @columbus8myhw But yeah, probably...

Comment: @kallixti Oh I'm really sorry I'm usually careful about that sorry

Comment: @columbus8myhw No worries... it happens all the time. :)